# Can my php output be seen by the client side in this Jquery script?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security

I have a page with a contact form. I would like email message to an email address. To allow my client to modify the email address the message will be sent to, I have created a custom field (ACF) which is recalled using:

```
<?php the_field('email_address'); ?>
```

I have used this in the following Jquery code, which posts it to the php file.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
            var address = <?php echo '"'; the_field('email_address'); echo '"'; ?>;
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var gender = $("#gender").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var subject = $("#subject").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/contact.php",
                data: { address: address, name: name, gender: gender, email: email, subject: subject, message: message }
            });
            return false;
});
```

The reason I am doing it this is way is to hide the email address from the client side, to avoid it being captured by spammers. I don't think this works. How would I go about making it invisible?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The reason I couldn't see it in the source was because I made a type in the field name. So I am now indeed looking for a way to hide the address. Sorry, and thank you! *facepalm*

Comment: you want to know its good way or not?

Answer (score 2):

If you View Source in the HTML page, you should find the email address in plain text right in the JavaScript code from your question, like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var address = "someone@somewhere.com";
```

Since it is in the HTML source code, it can easily be scraped.

You should also see it go over the wire in plain text (both from the server to the client when the page loads, and from the client to the server when the Ajax request is submitted), unless you are using https.

Rather than sending the email address to the client, why don't you send something that identifies the email address yet is meaningless outside of your system (like the primary key of the table it is in) and look it up in `contact.php`?

Comment: Interesting solution, but I can't see how I would make that work with any random address. What I am trying to achieve is that my client can change the destination email address in his Wordpress interface. A reference would have to be coded into the php file before hand, wouldn't it?

Comment: That destination email address, managed in Wordpress, is presumably stored in a database somewhere?  Your code shows that you are running PHP, which runs on the server, not on the client.

Comment: Yes it is stored in the Wordpress database, and I know PHP runs on the server, but I am entirely sure how I could use this Wordpress function in my php file. Is there any way I could like init the Wordpress functions in this file like you do with your page templates?

Comment: I don't know much about Wordpress programming, but the line `the_field('email_address')` retrieves the email address from a database table.  That table has some sort of key.  Perhaps it is the ID of the user that set that email preference in the first place?  Whatever ID you use to find the correct email address from the database can be passed to the HTML page instead of the email address itself.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't actually use that function in my php file since it doesn't have Wordpress initialised there. The solution I ended up going with was the encryption. As I said, this isn't a million visitor website and I think it will suffice. I have it up and running and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way to hide the e-mail address is to encrypt it.

Refer to [this](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/encode-decode.html) link. This might help you encode and decode Html & Javascript.

Comment: The best way to hide it is not to send it in the first place.  Send an identifier that is meaningless outside of your system, like a primary key.

Comment: But realisticly, this isn't a million visitor website and I doubt anyone would be willing to go as far as decrypting a simple email address just to send some spam when there are loads of other badly secured websites. Would something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/php-simplest-two-way-encryption) be suitable for my situation?