# Encrypt string when passing it through url as hyperlink and decrypt to echo out on next page?

Tags: php, encryption

I am using the following encrypt and decrypt script so that when a user clicks on a link containing my string this gets encrypted in the url and decrypted on the next page.

My string is being encrypted find but for some reason it won't decrypt on the next page. can someone please show me where i am going wrong? Thanks,

encryption.php:

```
<?php class encryption{
    private $config;

    public function __construct( $options=array() ){
        $this->config=array_merge(
            array(
                'cipher'    =>  MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                'mode'      =>  MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
                'key'       =>  FALSE,
                'iv'        =>  FALSE,
                'size'      =>  FALSE,
                'base64'    =>  TRUE,
                'salt'      =>  FALSE
            ),
            $options
        );
    }
    private function getivs( $config=object ){
        $config->size=mcrypt_get_iv_size( $config->cipher, $config->mode );
        $config->iv=mcrypt_create_iv( $config->size, MCRYPT_RAND );
    }
    public function encrypt( $data=NULL ){
        $config=(object)$this->config;
        $this->getivs( $config );
        $data=trim( $data );
        $module = mcrypt_module_open( $config->cipher, '', $config->mode, '' );
        mcrypt_generic_init( $module, $config->key, $config->iv );

        $output = $config->base64 ? base64_encode( mcrypt_generic( $module, $data ) ) : mcrypt_generic( $module, $data );

        mcrypt_generic_deinit( $module );
        mcrypt_module_close( $module );
        return $output;
    }
    public function decrypt( $data=NULL ){
        $config=(object)$this->config;
        $this->getivs( $config );
        mb_detect_order( 'auto' );
        $encoding=mb_detect_encoding( $data );
        if( !$data or is_null( $data ) or empty( $data ) or !$encoding or $data=='' or base64_decode( $data )=='' ) return FALSE;

        $module = mcrypt_module_open( $config->cipher, '', $config->mode, '' );
        mcrypt_generic_init( $module, $config->key, $config->iv );

        $output = $config->base64 ? rtrim( mdecrypt_generic( $module, base64_decode( $data ) ),"\0" ) : rtrim( mdecrypt_generic( $module, $data ),"\0" );

        mcrypt_generic_deinit( $module );
        mcrypt_module_close( $module );
        return urldecode( $output );
    }
}//end class

?>
```

new_supplier_listings.php:

```
session_start(); 
require_once 'dependables/encryption.php';

$string = 'NS12345';
        $enc=new encryption( array( 'key'=>'PlowFish' ) );
        $encrypted_string = $enc->encrypt( $string );


echo '<a href="ns_application.php?ns_request='.$encrypted_string.'">Click Here</a>';
```

ns_application.php:

```
require_once 'dependables/encryption.php'; 


$reference = isset($_GET['ns_request']) ? $_GET['ns_request'] : null;
$enc=new encryption( array( 'key'=>'PlowFish' ) );
$encrypted_string = $enc->encrypt( $reference );
echo $encrypted_string;
$decrypted_string=$enc->decrypt( $encrypted_string );
echo $decrypted_string;
```

Comment: You're using Rijndael-256 (which isn't AES btw) in ECB mode (which is the worst mode) and you're not authenticating your ciphertexts. This encryption library is **not** secure. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30189841/2224584 for a secure implementation.

Comment: @Mark harris please up-vote the answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you already sent an encrypted value to `ns_application.php`. And again you first `re-encrypt` it and the try to `decrypt` it that's why it's not giving you desired result. try this:

**`ns_application.php`:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
require_once 'encryption.php'; 


$reference = isset($_GET['ns_request']) ? $_GET['ns_request'] : null;
$enc=new encryption( array( 'key'=>'PlowFish' ) );

$decrypted_string=$enc->decrypt( $reference );
echo $decrypted_string;
?>
```

Output: `NS12345`.

Note:- though  your code is very fine but it's best practice to add `error reporting code`.

Comment: "though your code is very fine" actually it's very insecure

http://stackoverflow.com/a/30189841/2224584