# Hiding strings sent in the URL

Tags: php, encryption, base64

I want to pass some JSON code in the URL as a get parameter, but I don't want anyone will know what I'm sending and also I don't want to store in the DB the data.

Now I'm using base64 encoding to encrypt the JSON but it isn't safe.

Does anyone have another idea how can I do that?

```
$json = '{"key":"value"}';
$encoded_json = base64_encode($json);

header("Location: http://domain.com/data={$encoded_json}");
```

Comment: use HTTP POST at least

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP, Simplest Two Way Encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/php-simplest-two-way-encryption)

Comment: Note, base64 encoding is not _encryption_

Answer (score 1):

[Don't encrypt URL parameters](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php). Instead, use a separate look-up.

Also, [base64 isn't encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded), it's an encoding scheme.