# Simple PHP encryption and Deception

Tags: php, encryption

I would like to be able to encrypt (and by encrypt it has no means to be secure, so maybe obscure is the better word) a number so that the number to the naked eye has no relevance. The number is essentially going to be a lobby number so will look like

```
http://test.com/lobby/1035
```

I'm using PHP so if there is a way the url could look like

```
http://test.com/lobby/g4fg1
```

but when decrypted still go to lobby 1035.
I'm probably missing a trick but any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to protect against?

Comment: That's the thing with encrypting something. When you decrypt it, it is supposed to return the original value. Maybe you're looking for hashing the value, instead.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/php-simplest-two-way-encryption  Basically you could use any two way encryption.  But I wonder why you'd want to encrypt this value to begin with.

Comment: It would be just to hide it from the user, but to also make it bookmark-able, Scott has the perfect solution, thanks thought!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of encrypting a URL (which is foolhardy), why not add a separate field to the database table for the lobbies that contains a unique, short, randomly generated token and reference it based on that?

Comment: Sounds like a better more realistic approach, thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://hashids.org/php/ has a good implementation for this.

Comment: Oh god no. HashIDs is not secure by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: The question was not to have it secured, just to be obscured.

Comment: If you're trying to obscure something from the end-user, hashids is probably the worst way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You could convert every character to ASCII, shift it (number could be generated from the salt), convert it back. Then you would get kind of simply hashed input.

Function for that are [ord](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) and [chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php).

Comment: This is called a Caesar cipher, for the record. It can be brute forced in milliseconds.