# PHP encryption / deryption with recovery code

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I tried to rebuild the the encryption flow explained [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/48085)

**Encryption**

```
$password = 'pass123456';  //user password
$message = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.';

$Ku = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(256 / 8); //user-specific symmetric key
$Ru = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(256 / 8); //recovery code
$Su = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(256 / 8); //user salt ###STORED ON SERVER###

$hash = hash_pbkdf2('sha256', $password, $Su, 5000, 256 / 8, true);

$split = str_split($hash, 16);
$Vu = $split[0]; //password verification token ###STORED ON SERVER###
$Ek = $split[1]; //key to encrypt Ku


$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

$Eu = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $Ek, $Ku, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); ###STORED ON SERVER###
$Fu = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $Ru, $Ku, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); ###STORED ON SERVER###

$encryptedMessage = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $Ku, $message, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

**Decryption**

```
$hash = hash_pbkdf2('sha256', ###ENTERED PASSWORD###, ###STORED Su###, 5000, 256 / 8, true);
$split = str_split($hash, 16);
$Vu = $split[0];
$Ek = $split[1];


if($Vu != ###STORED Vu###) {
   => wrong password
} else {
   => correct password
}


$Ku = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $EK, ###STORED Eu###, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, ###STORED iv###);
$message = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $Ku, $encryptedMessage, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, ###STORED iv###);
```

If I have lost my password I can recover "Ku":

```
$Ku = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, ###REVOVERY KEY###, ###STORED Fu###, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, ###STORED iv###);
```

Is the code above secure? Is `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` random enough or is there a better possibility i.e. using mouse movement to generate a initialization number?

How should the "initialization vector" for mcrypt be handled? Is [this](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php#70947) correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Analysis in parts

It seems okay, but you might want to

- Increase the iterations of your PBKDF2 function. 5000 is quite low nowadays. Try a million.
- Rijndael with 256 bit block sizes is not as well analyzed as Rijndael with 128 bit block sizes which is AES. You should use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`. This will also improve compatibility to other implementations.
- You're not using ciphertext authentication which can detect (malicious) manipulation of your ciphertexts. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30189841/1816580) for a simple OpenSSL way of doing this.
- You're using MCrypt's default zero padding which is not good if your plaintexts end in 0x00 bytes. You would need to be careful when trimming those from your decrypted message.

> Is `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` random enough or is there a better possibility i.e. using mouse movement to generate a initialization number?

The initialization vector needs only to be unpredictable, but not secret. There are attacks which can exploit the system if the IV generation is predictable, but `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is supposed to be good. There is a small chance that it doesn't initialize properly and you'll be using non-"strong" random bytes (check the second argument), but even then depending on your system architecture the predictability of the IV might not be exploitable.

I also wonder how you want to get mouse movements in PHP since I'm assuming this runs on a server.

#### Analysis as a whole

That code seems to implement the [a good protocol described by Thomas Pronin](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/48085), but the protocol is slightly incomplete. Because there is nothing preventing an attacker to submit a random `Ru` and with it overwrite all the user's values.

During account creation (and password changing) you would need to also create a verification value for the recovery key. I think it would be sufficient to create

```
$VRu = hash_pbkdf2('sha256', $Ru, $Su, 1000, 256 / 8, true);
```

and store it on the server in case of recovery.

Since `Ru` is randomly generated, the number of iterations can be low, but it is still a costly operation. You should limit the use of the recovery operation to reduce denial of service attacks.

Comment: yes, correct it runs on a server, but I could generate it with javasript and then send it to the server

Comment: The protocol is good, but there is a problem during recovery. I've extended my answer.

Comment: Is there a security problem with bin2hex(Ru) to get a readable code?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it. An encoding on its own has no issues.

Comment: i.e. for printing it out. I suppose a user could have some problems to enter the characters from openssl_random_pseudo_bytes

Comment: I don't think a user would mind to enter 64 hex-chars during recovery, but you could use Base58 which has a higher density than Base16 (Hex), so the textual recovery code is not so long.