# How to use openssl for encryption?

Tags: php, curl, encryption

Essentially what I'm attempting to do is within my cURL API I would like clients using the API to have specific sensitive data encrypted on their server, before it leaves their server, then decrypted on my server.

I saw that you can use the `openssl_encrypt()` function, though I can't really find anything that's explaining it clear enough.

An example of the process is below:

**ON THE CLIENT'S SERVER SIDE:**

```
$dataToSend = 'mysupersecretstring';
// encrypt data
// connect and send to my server
```

**ON MY SERVER'S SIDE:**

```
$receivedString = '39bfy4f28d30g74fb34g79';
// string above is received
// string is decrypted decrypted
// $receivedString is now plaintext and can now be used on this server
```

I hope I'm explaining this clearly enough. If you have any questions please don't hesitate as it's rather important I have a valid solution to this.

Comment: Can you use an SSL certificate?

Comment: As I believe user2182349 is leading you, proper cryptography is hard to get right; using something that already exists, is well-understood and mature like SSL/TLS is a good idea if you don’t want to have subtle-but-critical failures of security.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP, Simplest Two Way Encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/php-simplest-two-way-encryption)

Comment: Yes, you can use OpenSSL in PHP to encrypt and decrypt a string, but you should ask yourself how you want to manage the encryption/decryption keys. Do you want to utilize asymmetric crypto or only symmetric? How will you securely distribute the keys?

Comment: Well, yes _I_ can use an SSL but I can't expect every single one of my clients to be using an SSL, unless my SSL encrypts their connection?

Comment: I would happily use any other encryption functions if they are available that any of you guys know about.

Comment: @ArtjomB. is there any way to encrypt and send data without keys? EDIT:  I can see that by keys that's the "password" parameter. This would be predefined as the client would be calling a method from a class they would be provided with. This class will be encrypted, so the key will never be seen.

Comment: `This class will be encrypted` - and where is the key for that stored?

Comment: You need a key otherwise that wouldn't be encryption. If give an obfuscated class to the client which includes the key, then you probably need to give every client a different custom class. You really should use the same class for everyone and give the client the class and the "API key".

Comment: In any case your original question is answered in the one that I linked. You should see a button to confirm that this is a duplicate above your question.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply: **Don't.**

[Use HTTPS](https://paragonie.com/white-paper/2015-secure-php-data-encryption) instead of relying on application layer cryptography for this specific use-case.

Unless you are a professional cryptographer with a specific use case for why you wish to avoid TLS (with public key pinning) and have a plan in place to manage encryption keys, you probably shouldn't write your own cryptography. [Or if you do, don't deploy/publish it](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it).

And if you do find yourself needing to encrypt information at the application layer (there *are* many valid use cases for encryption here), [learn all the pitfalls that you will encounter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30189841/2224584) and maybe consider using [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php) instead.