# Encrypting data with Mcrypt using a password instead of a key

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, mcrypt

Upon looking at Mcrypt_encrypt on the manual, I see that it requires a **key**. Is there another function or something that allows using a password instead? How would the code look then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you Encrypt and Decrypt a PHP String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string) particularly see the *"But I really want to use a password."* section of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30159120/1816580).

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks, that's a very helpful post and I will use that method.

Comment: This is what _key-derivation-functions_ like PBKDF2 are made for, to get a key from a password.

Comment: Thanks for that information @martinstoeckli, I'll look into that. I'm new to this encryption stuff.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try [openssl_encrypt()](https://php.net/openssl_encrypt) & [openssl_decrypt()](https://php.net/openssl_decrypt)

and check this answer for a very detailed example.

[Simplest two-way encryption using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/php-simplest-two-way-encryption/9262137#30189841)

Comment: If you simply link to another Q&A, then you probably should have commented instead of answering. If they are duplicates, then you should have flagged this question as a duplicate of the question you linked to.

Comment: @ArtjomB. sorry about that, when i answered this question i didn't have the 'comment everywhere' permission.

Answer (score -1):

You ca use `crypt` php function as follows. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

```
<?php
   $hashed_password = crypt('mypassword');
?>
```

Comment: I have to be able to encrypt and decrypt the data. Isn't crypt one-way? I am not wanting to hash a password, I am wanting to create an encryption based on a password.

Comment: OP is asking about Password-based Encryption and not "encrypting" a password.