# iOS - How to generate random IV in ECB mode?

Tags: php, ios, encryption

I want to generate random IV in iOS which is base on the below code:

```
mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
```

Is anybody can tell me how to generate random IV in iOS same with the above php?
Thank you.

Comment: [ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29) doesn't use an IV, so you can just use an empty string.

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Answer (score 0):

This question is unanswerable (it's akin to "what is the sound of one hand clapping?"), but in the interest of guiding people who come upon it in the future:

- As Artjom B. pointed out in the comments, ECB mode doesn't accept an IV
- [Don't write crypto code](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it) (the entire CryptoFails blog is worth reading)
- [ECB mode sucks for security](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/)

What to do instead: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30189841/2224584).

Comment: Understood. Thank you.