# How to create signature using PHP

Tags: php, rsa, digital-signature, sha256, public-key

I need to use an API but first to login I need to create signature.

```
1. Concatenate the API key with the current timestamp in the format below:
<<APIKEY>>_<<timestamp(yyyy'-'MM'-'ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ)>>
```

and this step is easy:

```
hash('sha256', $data);
```

result is:
9952375a30708b46739986482303cae30ad51fc9a362b5794d298dfc22f7ec02
and this is correct result

The next step is:

```
2. The combination of the created signature along with the provided API secret key will act as the
digital signature of the call.
```

I have API secret key like:

```
    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
9IGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCgBSU90PX4WyXFAZ/+M84dJNEi
/0j5OermfydTU4g2JvnpO6BOQjNpb5+mOLjVoij7DWTdDtx1WThRm04N3DVuyh+a
5cledvMbcngvyiXpQCdskT9bVmI4QLbmRny46S7MER1jhziMQRfRw9gbmlB2iCEq
n21kDr842Q+WDtLE4QIDAQA9
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

How I can get Digital signature with a combination of created signature and provided API secret key?

There is an Python example like:

```
key = api_key + '_' + timestamp

print "message", key

sha_hash = hashlib.sha256(key).hexdigest()

print "sha256 hash:", sha_hash


rsa_key = RSA.importKey(pub_key)
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsa_key)
signature = base64.encodestring(cipher.encrypt(sha_hash))
```

**but how I can get signature using PHP?**

Comment: Not sure what platform you are on but looked at [`openssl_encrypt`](https://www.php.net/openssl_encrypt)?

Comment: Yes, I think I need to use openssl_encript

Comment: There are some other options but I figure openssl is generally maintained on most systems. FWIW: [Simplest two-way encryption using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/simplest-two-way-encryption-using-php) - old one, some info might be outdated.

Comment: @ficuscr Can you please write an answer on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are numerous ways to accomplish this, I recommend leveraging the [**openssl_public_encrypt**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) method. There are other *crypt* functions and even pure PHP implementations of RSA but they are likely not as current and well maintained as openSSL is going to be on a linux system. Don't forget all the disruption in SSL/TLS these last years. Everything from retiring older protocols and weaker cyphers to POODLE type exploits.

If for whatever reason that is not an option I would probably look into phpseclib. https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib

Really might come down to what makes the most sense for your project... OS, portability, speed, etc.

Here is that Python snippet converted to equivalent PHP code.

```
<?php
$key = $api_key . '_' . $timestamp;

echo "message:" . $key;

$sha_hash = hash('sha256', $key);

echo "sha256 hash:" .  $sha_hash;

$rsa_key = "your public key goes in here"; //see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-public.php

openssl_public_encrypt($sha_hash, $encrypted, $rsa_key);
$signature = base64_encode($encrypted);
```

Comment: This is not a signature, it is RSA encryption.