# How to encrypt/hash data in $_GET in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm a beginner in `PHP`.
Is it possible to hash `$_GET` data before sending it?

For example, I want to redirect to :

`samplepage.php?id=1`

How do I turn it into:

`samplepage.php?id=6rP7Fre4QkZShmTbpCuhuV.GV/BYPfj2kj7K`

And then how to I `decode` this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest two-way encryption using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/simplest-two-way-encryption-using-php)

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add `base64_encode()` to encode and `base64_decode()` to decode.

`base64_decode($_GET['id'])` will give you the original value.